# Mongodb remove object from array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to remove an object form an array based on the name(Ticker) of an object. Others have also asked this question and I have tried many of their solutions but I just cant get it to work. It never actually performs the task of removing anything.

Here is my schema:

```
{
    _id : 1234 
    email : me@me.com 
    pass : password  
    stock : [ 
        {
        Ticker : TSLA 
        Market : Nasdaq 
        Notes : [ 
            "Buy at 700", 
            "Sell at 1000"
            ] 
        },
        {
        Ticker : AAPL 
        Market : Nasdaq 
        Notes : [ 
            "Buy at 110", 
            "Sell at 140"
            ] 
        },
    
    ]
}
```

Here is what I currently have, but I've also tried a few other combinations of commands:

```
router.post(`/watchlist/remove/:email/:pass/:stock`, (req, res) => {
    var email = req.params.email
    var pass = req.params.pass
    var tempStock = req.params.stock


    userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email  }, { $pull : {'stock.Ticker' : tempStock} }   , (documents, err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(documents)
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might help

```
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email  }, { $pull:{stock:{Ticker : tempStock}}}, (documents, err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        else {
            res.send(documents)
        }
    })
```

Also you might want to `double-check` if you are receiving value in `tempStock` variable

Comment: I didn't realize earlier but the tempStock was receiving an object and not just a string. Thanks for the help your code worked once I sorted tempStock out.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this:

```
userModel.findOneAndUpdate({
    "email": email,
    "stock.Ticker": tempStock
}, {
    "$pull": {
        "stock": {
            "Ticker": tempStock
        }
    }
}, (documents, err) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    else {
        res.send(documents)
    }
})
```